# Is there a way to have a countdown timer while waiting for input?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a simple game that requires the user's input before the timer runs out.

Basically, the page will load with a  time, and wait for the user to say the correct answer. If the time runs out, the game is over, but if the user gets it right, he moves on to the next question.

(i've got the speech part worked out, I just need to figure out the timer)

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't see where is the problem. Create a Timer and countdown :D

Comment: I've never done any windows phone apps before, and i'm still fairly new to c#, so i'm not even sure what to google.

Comment: Please specify your problem. You don't know how to show countdown or how to countdown or what :)?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to show it, i just need to have a timer stop whatever is going on if time runs out and the user hasn't answered.

Comment: Google how to use "Timer" class and do what is necessary. Also I'll recommend you wpftutorial.net to understand XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Add Using Statement
using System.Windows.Threading;

//Create Timer
DispatcherTimer mytimer;

//Setup Timer
myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
myTimer.Interval = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;

// When you type the +=, this method skeleton should come up
// automatically. But type this in if it doesn't.
void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This runs when ever the timer Goes Off (In this case every 10 sec)
}

//Run Timer
myTimer.Start()

//Stop Timer
myTimer.Stop()
```

Does this solve your question?